# Python: Create New Column in Dataframe that shows the Sum of values in Another Column by the Category in a Third Column

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, sum, row

I want to ultimately create the "Adjusted Ratios" column in my data frame by doing the following steps:

1) Take the sum of the "Ratio" column by "Account" --> creates "Sum of Ratios" column
2) Divide each row of the "Ratio" column by the "Sum of Ratios" column --> creates "Adjusted Ratios"

In my own code, I used a work around method.  I did a groupby sum of the "Ratio" column by "Account"...then merged it back to my original dataframe.  Finally, I derived "Adjusted Ratios" column by simply dividing the two previous columns.

But I am looking for a more straightforward way to do the above w/o having to merge datasets together.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` which keeps the length of the result and thus can be directly assigned back to the original data frame as a new column:

```
(df.assign(SumOfRatios = df.groupby('Account').Ratio.transform('sum'))
   .assign(AdjustedRatios = lambda x: x.Ratio/x.SumOfRatios))
```